# Emacs Verilog 'compilation exited abnormally with code 255'

Tags: emacs, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, iverilog

```
module FullAdder (a, b, ci, r, co);
   input a, b, ci;
   output r, co;

   assign r = a ^ b ^ ci;
   assign co = (a&b) | ((a^b)&ci);

endmodule // FullAdder
```

```
module adder_4bit (A, B, ci, R, co);
   input [3:0] A, B; // [MSB:LSB]
   input       ci;
   output [3:0] R;
   output   co;
   wire [2:0]   c;
   
   // FullAdder i0 (.a(A[0]), .b(B[0]), .ci(ci), .r(R[0]), .co(c[0]));
   // FullAdder i1 (.a(A[1]), .b(B[1]), .ci(c[0]), .r(R[1]), .co(c[1]));
   // FullAdder i2 (.a(A[2]), .b(B[2]), .ci(c[1]), .r(R[2]), .co(c[2]));
   // FullAdder i3 (.a(A[3]), .b(B[3]), .ci(c[2]), .r(R[3]), .co(co));

   FullAdder i[3:0] (.a(A[3:0]), .b(B[3:0]), .ci({c[2:0],ci}), .r(R[3:0]), .co({co,c[2:0]}));

endmodule // adder_4bit
```

```
module adder_nbit (a, b, m, s, co, v);
   parameter N = 32; // 32 bit subtractor
   input [N-1:0] a, b;
   input     m;
   output [N-1:0] s;
   output    co, v;
   wire [N/4-1:0]     c;
   wire [N-1:0]       bi;

   genvar     i;

   assign bi[0] = b[0] ^ m;
   assign bi[1] = b[1] ^ m;
   assign bi[2] = b[2] ^ m;
   assign bi[3] = b[3] ^ m;

   adder_4bit add0(.A(a[3:0]), .B(bi[3:0]), .ci(m), .R(s[3:0]), .co(c[0]));

   generate
      for (i=1; i<=N/4-1; i=i+1) begin:bit
     assign bi[i*4] = b[i*4] ^ m;
     assign bi[i*4+1] = b[i*4+1] ^ m;
     assign bi[i*4+2] = b[i*4+2] ^ m;
     assign bi[i*4+3] = b[i*4+3] ^ m;
     adder_4bit add(.A(a[i*4+3:i*4]), .B(bi[i*4+3:i*4]), .ci(c[i-1]), .R(s[i*4+3:i*4]), .co(c[i]));
      end
   endgenerate

   assign co = c[N/4-1]; // carry
   assign v = c[N/4-2] ^ co; // overflow
endmodule // adder_nbit
```

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
`include "FullAdder.v"
`include "adder_4bit.v"
`include "adder_nbit.v"

module subtractor_nbit_tb;
   parameter N = 32;
   reg [N-1:0] A, B;
   reg       M;
   wire [N-1:0] S;
   wire       CO, V;
   adder_nbit i0 (.a(A), .b(B), .m(M), .s(S), .co(CO), .v(V));

   initial
     begin
    $dumpfile ("subtractor_nbit_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, subtractor_nbit_tb);
    M=1; // subtractor
    A=0;
    B=0;

    #10 A=302;
    
    #10 B=100;
    
    #10 A=400;

    #10 B=203;

    #10 $finish;

     end // initial begin
endmodule // adder_4bit_tb
```

I'm making an n-bit subtractor with a 4-bit adder made with Fulladder. I put parameter N into n-bit subtractor. Depending on this N value, it was changed to 32, 36, or 40 bit subtracter.

When I run the simulation, 'compilation exited abnormally with code 255' error appears. What's wrong with the code?

I tried changing the xor method of b and m and changing the range of the `for` loop, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is not very specific.  If it is coming from emacs, then run the code directly on a simulator.

Since you are using `iverilog`, we can run it on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/jSN6).  However, we still see a generic error message.

But, when run on the Cadence simulator, the error is much more meaningful:

```
     for (i=1; i<=N/4-1; i=i+1) begin:bit
                                        |
xmvlog: *E,FNDKWD (testbench.sv,47|40): A SystemVerilog keyword was found where an identifier was expected.
```

One way to fix this error is to change `bit` to another name, like `bits`.  That allows the code to compile without errors.

---

The original code compiles cleanly if you disable SystemVerilog features in your simulator.  For example, running `iverilog` without the `-g2012` option.  However, it is better to write code that compiles with SV features enabled.